# Getting hash parameters from request url

Tags: javascript

I have such url - http://www.coolsite.com/daily-plan/#id=1
What the easiest way to parse that string and read a hash value (the value after #id=)?
Thank you

Comment: Check out this. Essentially anything after the `#` isn't sent to the server, so it has no clue about it. What this person did was inject some javascript in the server endpoint that handles the request to then fetch the data from the URL and send it back to the server https://github.com/sosodev/twitchOAuth/blob/main/twitchoauth.go#L28

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On client side (i.e. from JavaScript) you can check `window.location.hash` to get hash. On server side, general answer is 'it is impossible' since hash is not sent in request to server.

**Upd:** I maybe misunderstood the question. My answer is about how to get hash part of url either in browser or in server side code during request processing, not about string processing.

**Upd2:** Answer to comment here because it doesn't fit in comment.

How does it work when user clicks on your navigational links?

I assume hash is changed and corresponding content is downloaded via AJAX request from web service or REST.

For example if your user has URL www.example.com in his browser and this page shows a list of product categories. User clicks one category and URL changes to www.example.com/#id=5 and products from that category(with ID=5) are downloaded via AJAX and shown on the page. No postback, only partial page refresh.

Is this close to your scenario?

Now you want user to paste/enter www.example.com/#id=5 directly in the browser address bar and go directly to list of products in that category.

But **/#id=5 is not sent to server with request** by the browser, so there is no way to get that value on server side, and you can do nothing about it since it is the browser decided not to send this data and you don't have it on server side.

In our project we use solution when server returns only common page code/html, i.e. header, footer, without main/center part of the page. Then there is a JavaScript code which executes right after this common HTML loaded. It takes `window.location.hash` and sends it to web service via AJAX and web service returns content (HTML) for the main part of the page.

Comment: Let me explain: I did some site with ajax navigation. Later, I decided to use a jQuery BBQ library in order to give oportunity to store all steps in browser's history. And now I want to create such thing - if user goes to default page - some list is being generated. In case of he is going to /#id=5 the server should generate another content. So my problem is that I can'r read an #id's value on server side.

Comment: I've answered in UPD2 in the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks Kyrill, I have exactly the same problem you described. In your solution I don't like the double or maybe triple AJAX requests to server, but apparently it is a single solution. Thank you

Answer (score 15):

```
new URI("http://.../abc#xyz").getFragment();
```

See the [Javadocs for URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

Comment: Well but how do you get `/abc#xyz` in the first place?

Comment: The question, as originally asked, didn't mention anything about client/server/browser or whatever. It just said you have this URL string, how do you extract the fragment, which is what my answer covers.

Comment: Well technically, yes, fair enough. But then that's just a String operation `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to capture anchor links. Works across all web frameworks.

I'll use an example scenario to illustrate: let's say we need to capture a deep URL http://server.com**/#/xyz** requested by an unauthenticated user so that they can be redirected to that deep URL post-login.

1. The unauthenticated user requests http://server.com**/#/xyz** (everything from the '#' onwards is not sent to the server).
2. All the server knows is that the user wants http://server.com/ and that they are unauthenticated. Server redirects the user to a login form.
3. Here's the clever bit: the client is still waiting on their original request so if the server includes a hidden element in the login form with some JS that references window.location.href, it can capture the full URL **of the original request** complete with the anchor portion:

   ```
   <form action="/login" method="post">
     <div>
       <label>Username:</label>
       <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
     </div>
     <div>
       <label>Password:</label>
       <input type="password" name="password"/>
     </div>
     <!-- XXXXXXXXX CLEVER BIT XXXXXXXXXX-->
     <script>
       document.write('<input type="hidden" name="from" value="'+document.location.href+'"/>');
     </script>
     <!-- XXXXXXXXXX-->
     <div>
       <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```
4. The user authenticates themself and the original URL is sent with the POST. The server can then relay the user to the original deep URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
String url = " http://www.coolsite.com/daily-plan/#id=1";
int sharpPos = url.indexOf('#');
String q = null;
if (sharpPos >= 0) {
    q = url.substring(sharpPos);
}
```

Surely you can use various methods of string manipulation including regular expressions.

But actually your example is strange. Typically parameters of URL are passed after question mark. In this case you can just use standard class URL:

`String q = new URL(" http://www.coolsite.com/daily-plan?id=1").getQuery();`

Comment: I agree that usually I see parameters passed after a question mark. Sometimes however I have seen it done as a hash .. but seldom and on more complicated code.

Answer (score -1):

what you are using to do this ?

If you are using jsp or servlet following will be useful to you

```
if (request.getParameter("#id") == null) {
    out.println("Please enter your name.");
} else {
    out.println("Hello <b>"+request.getParameter(i)+"</b>!");
}
```

If you are using javascript for it following function will be useful to you

```
function getURLParameters() 
{
var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();

if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
{
    var arrParams = sURL.split("?");

    var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");

    var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
    var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);

    var i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
    {
        var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
        arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
        if (sParam[1] != "")
            arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
        else
            arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
    }

    for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
    {
        alert(arrParamNames[i]+" = "+ arrParamValues[i]);
    }
}
else
{
    alert("No parameters.");
}
   }
```

Comment: It seems that there is no any way to read hash variables on server-side

Comment: if you want to read it at server side servlet can do this it gives parameter at server side as shown in first code-snippet. You will get HttpRequest object request in your servlet through which you can get parameters of it.

Comment: request.getParameter("#id"), request.getAttribute("#id") do not works.

Comment: what error does it give? where did you written this code snippet?

Comment: There is no any error. It returns null. I am using a Spring MVC. So I am trying to get request parameter in controller method

Comment: Is request is a object of HttpServletRequest ? and try for request.getParameter(0)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4774/discussion-between-nkognito-and-hemant-metalia)

Answer (score -2):

**REPLACE the '#' with '?'** when parsing the url. Check the code below

```
String url = "http://www.coolsite.com/daily-plan/#id=1";
String urlNew = url.replace("#", "?");
String id = Uri.parse(urlNew).getQueryParameter("id");
```

Comment: this code obviously does not respect the possibility of query parameters already present in the url... I would counsel against this solution as it misuses a concept and only works for a special case.

Answer (score -3):

If you URL will the same as you write and doesn't contains anythins else then whis code on Java will help you

```
 String val = "http://www.coolsite.com/daily-plan/#id=1";
 System.out.println(val.split("#id")[1]);
```

Don't forget check to null value.

P.S. If you use servlet you can get this parameter from request.getAttribute("id").

With best regards, 
Psycho

Comment: request.getParameter("#id"), request.getAttribute("#id") do not works

Comment: you can't get your parameter on servlet, because your url doesn't correct sample is http://www.coolsite.com/daily-plan/?id=1" then my sample code will work and give you your parameter.( request.getAttribute("id"))

Comment: I know that my url not correct. Actually its correct, but passing parameters is not correct. So my question is - is there any way to read that #id parameter on server-side

Comment: No, this parameter doesn't sent to server by default. Byt you can only get this parameter on client side and send it to server manually. How do you call your servlet? Html form? Or call jQuery methods?

Comment: The problem is that I am using jQuery BBQ plugin in order to make a browser's back button enabled. But when I call the page for the first time - the content already generated on server-side.

Answer (score -3):

if your url get from OAuth callback,then you can't!
because the full url won't send to service because of hash(#)