# # in URL skipping all parameter after that

Tags: javascript, php, html

When submitting form using get method if we pass # character in any field it skips all parameter after that field.

e.g.

> bookmy_car.php?pod=6&room_id=32&starthour=14&startminute=00&startday=07&startmonth=08&startyear=2015&endhour=16&endminute=00&endday=07&endmonth=08&endyear=2015&end_date=1438927200&email_conf=1&cost_code=&desc=Trip description&**trip_comment=#**&day_rate=68.00&hourly_rate=6.60&hourly_km_rate=0.35&dur_hours=2
>   hours&location_charge=0.00&damage_cover_charge=5.00&total_free_kms=&longterm=0&rt=&minbooking=3600&returl=&returl_newid=&rep_id=&edit_type=&insPlanid=3&plan_name=goOccasional&id=3&driver_username_id=2&

How do we protect it? I tried `escape()` and `encodeURI()` function of JavaScript, it does not help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby

Comment: I don't think that you can solve this problem due to the fact, that the browser won't send it to the server...
But here is a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033537/getting-hash-parameters-from-request-url

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - get value from URL after # sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because with hashbang in query string `#` it is interpreted as `location.hash` and hot processed as GET parameters. You need to properly encode URI before you use it. For example with `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
alert( encodeURIComponent('trip_comment=#') )
```

Comment: it does not solve, i already tried it earlier. do one thing create a php page, and do print_r($_GET) of url which i mentioned and see.

Comment: You need to encode GET parameters. So `trip_comment=#` becomes `trip_comment%3D%23`. You should encode every parameter ideally. Not sure how you are constructing URL but you should use proper methods. there are some in both JS and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @dgsq . But i prefer using only `encodeURI` so that he can get the uri as it is in the next page.

```js
alert( encodeURI('&trip_comment=#&day_rate=68.00') )
```

Comment: it does not solve, i already tried it earlier. do one thing create a php page, and do print_r($_GET) of url which i mentioned and see.