# Handle # character in spring web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to add an exception for security rules in Spring but getting 401 meaning my mapping is not recognized. The uri is `/test/acc#v1=1&v2=2...`

I have security configured:
`http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/test/acc*{v:.+}")`

and

`http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/test/acc*")`

And my controller annotation is:

```
@GetMapping("/test/acc{suffix:.+}")
```

None of it works, I keep on getting 401. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: That's a *URL fragment* and isn't even sent to the server.

Comment: Can I get Spring to process this fragment?

Comment: No. Spring will never see the fragment; it stays on the browser.

Comment: Thanks, will create a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general consensus that Server does not receive the URL fragmentation details and it is applicable for all major servers java based servers like tomcat, jetty..etc [please refer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033537/getting-hash-parameters-from-request-url)