# JavaScript variable in JSP expression tags

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, variables

I have this JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function greetings() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        if (hash != "") {
            var name = "<%= Encode.forJavaScriptBlock(hash) %>";
            document.write("<h1> Hello " + name + "!</h1>");    
        }
        else {
            document.write("<h1>Welcome Back!</h1>");       
        }
    }
    greetings();
</script>
```

When I run this I receive the following error related to the declaration line of the *name* variable:

> hash cannot be resolved to a variable

I don't understand why as the hash variable seems in scope to me.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268356/assign-javascript-variable-to-java-variable-in-jsp .  Short answer: you can't call Java code such as `Encode.forJavaScriptBlock` in a JavaScript function.

Comment: @LukeWoodward and what about this: https://www2.owasp.org/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html#forJavaScript-java.lang.String-

Comment: You can't call any Java code from your JavaScript function.  This has been explained in the question I linked to, and in the questions linked to that one.  Besides, I'm not sure what you're trying to use this method to achieve.

Comment: @LukeWoodward this is what I want to do: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#guideline

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some misunderstanding of when your Java and JavaScript code executes.

The code within your JSP gets compiled into Java code that will look something like the following:

```
out.println("<script>");
out.println("    function greetings() {");
out.println("        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);");
out.println("        if (hash != \"\") {");
out.print("            var name = \"");
out.print(Encode.forJavaScriptBlock(hash));
out.println("\";");
out.println("            document.write(\"<h1> Hello \" + name + \"!</h1>\");");
out.println("        }");
out.println("        else {");
out.println("            document.write(\"<h1>Welcome Back!</h1>\");");
out.println("        }");
out.println("    }");
out.println("    greetings();");
out.println("</script>");
```

The server doesn't process the JavaScript code within the `<script>` element.  To the server, that's just a load of text it sends straight to the browser without any further processing.  However, within your JSP you have a scriptlet `<%= Encode.forJavaScriptBlock(hash) %>`, and the contents of this does gets written into the compiled Java code.  This line attempts to refer to a Java variable named `hash`, but there is no such thing: whilst your JavaScript code does contain a variable named `hash`, that (a) will never exist on the server, where your JSP runs, and (b) won't exist in the user's browser until the page has been sent to the browser, and that will be after the JSP has finished running.

This is why you are getting the error you are.

Ultimately, it seems you are trying to prevent malicious data being inserted into your web page, but without quite understanding how to do this.  It seems you would be better off following Rule #6 from the cheat sheet you link to, by having an `<h1>` element somewhere in your page, with an ID, and modifying your JavaScript function to change the text content of this instead, i.e.

```
<h1 id="greeting-message">

<script>
    function greetings() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        var greetingElement = document.getElementById("greeting-message");
        if (hash != "") {
            greetingElement.textContent = "Hello " + hash + "!";
        }
        else {
            greetingElement.textContent = "Welcome Back!";
        }
    }
    greetings();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and solution. What I don't understand is that at this link https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#guideline this seems used like I want, at least in the examples provided. I totally understand what you are saying, but I don't understand so how the example from OWASP could work. I don't want to use .textContent, I just want to use the library provided. Could you maybe post an example that uses that? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @ibrahim87: the OWASP library is intended to be used with data on the server.   Often this would be with data read from a database.  Your example, using the hash of a URL, isn't useful here as browsers don't send the hash to the server (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033537)).  Instead of using the hash, could you perhaps try using query-string parameters?  To do this, replace `#someone` in the URL with `?user=someone` and use `request.getParameter("user")` in the JSP to get the value `someone`.